# How to link to specific row in google sheets from sidebar

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very large google sheet document that I am creating for work. I have written a short script to create a sidebar from a separate HTML file. The script is as follows:

```
  function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('MaintainRegistry')
  .addItem('GenerateContractTemplate', 'generateContractTemplate')
  .addToUi();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Sidebar').addItem('Open', 'openSidebar').addToUi(); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Sidebar').addItem('Open', 'openSidebar').addToUi();
}
```

The function is :

```
function openSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

And the simple HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" 
crossorigin="anonymous">


<style type = "text/css">

button {
width: 150px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

#header {
background-color: rgb(47,129,183);
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}



</style>

</head>



<body>

<div id="header">
<h1> Index </h1>
</div>

<div class="text-center">

<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Hotel name</button>
</p>


<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Periods</button>
</p>

<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contract template</button>
</p>

<p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Non renewals</button>
</p>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Essentially this is just a simple sidebar and I want the buttons to take the user to a specific place in the spreadsheet. There are over 60 columns so if the user clicks on 'hotel name' I want it to lead them to for example, column AE etc...

How can this be done? I have no idea what to reference in the link and obviously don't want this to open a new page either - just skip straight to the right column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to your gs file. Change the sheet name and row and column of each yo where you want to position to.

```
function hotel(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=12
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function periods(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=13
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function contracttemplate(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=14
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function nonrenewals(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=15
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
```

In the HTML file, I added a reference to jquery. I changed the buttons to have unique ids and added script yo handle the button clicks and call the new functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type = "text/css">
button {
width: 150px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}
#header {
background-color: rgb(47,129,183);
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1> Index </h1>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<p>
<input id="Button1" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Hotel name">
</p>
<p>
<input id="Button2" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Periods">
</p>
<p>
<input id="Button3" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
value="Contract template">
</p>
<p>
<input id="Button4" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Non 
renewals">
</p>
</div>
</body>
   <script>
 $("#Button1").on('click',function(){
    google.script.run.hotel()
    google.script.host.editor.focus()
 });
  $("#Button2").on('click',function(){
    google.script.run.periods()
    google.script.host.editor.focus()
 });
 $("#Button3").on('click',function(){
    google.script.run.contracttemplate()
    google.script.host.editor.focus()
 });
  $("#Button4").on('click',function(){
    google.script.run. nonrenewals()
    google.script.host.editor.focus()
 });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks so much :) Just a small amendment I wanted to make - is there a way I can reference the row that the user is in already? So for example is the user is on row 450, when they click a button it should send them to the relevant column. But I don't really want to send them back to the top of the spreadsheet as that seems a little counterproductive. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I changed the above script to go to the active row. If this solves your problem, please approve the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: awesome ! Cheers so much